# Magento 2.3.5 Customer getting wrong reset password link in email

Tags: customer-account, store-view, multidomain, magento2.3.5-p2, forgot-password

We have 2 store_view and both are pointed on the different domain.

```
Desktop Store URL: www.example.com
    
Mobile Store URL: m.example.com
```

Customers are sharing on the website.

Customer account created in the desktop store but he wants to reset his password inside the mobile store.

When the customer is triggering an email of Forgot password from the Mobile store then he must get the reset password link of the mobile store but he is getting the reset password link of Desktop Store.

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you arride core model? if yes, you me have done someting wrong in email template of reset password

Comment: No, not override.